# Drop rows and reindex the data frame

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe of 1000 rows. Of which I have removed 20 rows.
Now I want to reindex the df to (0-979) rows.

in_val = list(range(30,50)) # no of rows dropped
df.drop(in_val, inplace=True)

The the df is with 980 rows, but the index is not 0-979.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

```
df.drop(in_val).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
`df.reset_index(inplace=True)`